# Random numbers in specific range C#

Tags: c#

I need to print the numbers from `1` to `n` in a random order. I achieved this by using `System.Random`, but it resulted in numbers in range of 1-5. I want to randomise all of numbers in this range.

**This is my code:**

```
Random r = new Random();

int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int [] a=new int[n];

for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++){
    a[i] = r.Next(1,n);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: So, you want to print 1-5 in random order?

Comment: Sorry, i want to print 1-n in random order.

Comment: Start by changing the upper bound r.Next(1,6) to include 5 to the range

Comment: I believe that after op's update, he should be able to get it done.

Comment: @BramDriesen : possible duplicate, except the two questions don't have anything in common except using the words random and range...

Comment: @-Falanwe: It's the same thing. If you know how to use a random you can also change the range of it...

Comment: @BramDriesen : the OP asks how to get a permutation of a given set, and you point to a question asking how to get **one** random number in a range. Nothing in common there.

Answer (score 7):

```
Random r = new Random();
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int[] a = Enumerable.Range(1, n).OrderBy(_ => r.Next()).ToArray();
```

Basic idea - create all numbers in the range and shuffle them.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an way you can do it

```
Random random = new Random();
int [] a = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).OrderBy(b => random.Next()).ToArray() ; 

foreach (var item in a ) 
{
    Console.Write(item + " ") ; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure you want a random order over your whole set (i.e. you will use every value of your new ordering), use Ulugbek or Ksv3n ' answers. For reference:

```
var random = new Random();
var randomOrder = Enumerable.Range(1,n).OrderBy(_ => random.Next());
```

But you might want to only take the first few. Then you can use a lazy implementation, more efficient if n is big and you only need the first few, but far less if you enumerate through the whole permutation.

```
IEnumerable<T> RandomOrder<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    var remaining = source.ToList();
    var random = new Random();
    while (remaining.Any())
    {
        var index = random.Next(remaining.Length);
        yield return remaining[index];
        remaining.RemoveAt(index);
    }
}

var randomOrder = RandomOrder(Enumerable.Range(1,n));
```

The best method to use depends on your use case. Usually it's the former, but not always.

Answer (score 0):

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Random randNum = new Random();
            int[] rArray= Enumerable
                .Repeat(0, n)
                .Select(i => randNum.Next(1, 10)) // whatever your range is
                .ToArray();

            foreach (var a in rArray){
                Console.WriteLine(" " + a);

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```